# Enumeration of event handlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to list all event handlers an html element supports?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106

Comment: @crescentfresh - I think that quesiton is different.  There, they asked how to find out what is actively observing.  I believe Joseph here is asking what *could* an observer be observing.

Comment: thanks Matt, that's exactly what I meant.. I think the article suggested by 'Tim Down' could do the trick. haven't tested it yet though.

thanks all!